# Error in deleting a row in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to delete a row from my table, but it's throws following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ReportPageOrder.id' in 'field list'
```

I'm using CakePHP 2.x PHP framework.

Following is my code:

```
$this->ReportPageOrder->deleteAll(array('report_id'=> 7, 'page_id' => 3));
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_report_page_orders` (
  `report_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `page_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `order` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`report_id`,`page_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work :

```
$this->ReportPageOrder->deleteAll(array( 'ReportPageOrder.report_id'=>7,'ReportPageOrder.page_id'=> 3),false);
```

reference :
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/models/deleting-data.html